# Cargar Celdas epecificas de un Excel a un datagridview de winform en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Saudos, En un tab control tengo dos pestañas, cada una tiene un grid el primer grid debe insertar n cantidad de valores en celdas especificas de un excel y el segundo debe recibir el resulado de operaciones realizadas en el mismo excel pero de otra hoja y devolverlos en el segundo grid tambien de celdas especificas, solo he logrado la importacion del excel pero este me trae todo lo que encuentra en el excel al grid. Agardeceria su apoyo.

```
class Importar
    {
        OleDbConnection conexion;
        OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter;
        DataTable dt;
        public string celda { get; set; }

        public void ImportarExcel (DataGridView dgv, string nombreHoja)
        {
            string ruta = "";
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openfile.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
                openfile.Title = "";

                if (openfile.ShowDialog () == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (openfile.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                    {
                        ruta = openfile.FileName;
                    }
                }

                conexion = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+"Data Source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");
                MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + nombreHoja + "$]", conexion);
                dt = new DataTable();
                MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                //celda = dt.Rows[6][2].ToString();
                dgv.DataSource = dt;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te trae todo porque estas haciendo un select *. deberias agregar una clausula where para que filtre los resultados. y que intentaste para mandar los datos al excel?

Comment: ahi es donde se me hace dificl como declarar el where que apunte a una celda en especifico, entiendo que las filas son rows y las columnas cell si no estoy mal.

Comment: la hoja de excel es como si fuera una tabla de una base de datos.. pero no podemos ayudarte con el where, porque no sabemos nada sobre tus datos ni que necesitas filtrar.

Comment: Por favor, cualquier cosa que necesites aclarar, tenes el boton [edit] para agregarlo a la pregunta.

Comment: entiendo, a ver si me explico, en la tabla siguiente supongamos que quiero el ultimo dato que seria CHEVY AVEO que se encuentra en la celda A5 y el motor que seria la celda C5 del excel, lo demas no importaria

Comment: Si no sabes cual es el ultimo registro, vas a tener que recorrer la tabla resultado para quedarte solo con el ultimo.

Comment: Utiliza un datareader en lugar de un dataadapter, o filtra la cantidad de filas que extraeras

Comment: ok intentare las opciones propuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con ayuda de un compañero y googleando por ahi, se logro hacer con interop tanto a importacion del excel al grid como la exportacion, por si le sirviera a alguien ahi les dejo el codigo, Saludos.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace excelEPPlus
{
class MyExcel
{

    public static BindingList<CROMA> cromaList = new BindingList<CROMA>();
    //public static BindingList<CROMA2> cromaList2 = new BindingList<CROMA2>();
    private static Excel.Application Myapp = null;
    private static Excel.Workbook LibroExcel = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet HojaExcel = null;
    private static Excel.Worksheet HojaExcelEnt = null;
    private static int lastRow = 8;

    public static List<string> ListaRangos = new List<string>() { "C5:C22", "F9:F26", "I2:I20", "L10:L27" };

    public static void InicializarExcel()
    {
        Myapp = new Excel.Application();
        LibroExcel = Myapp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\One323\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\excelEPPlus\excelEPPlus\Archivos\prueba.xlsx");
        HojaExcel = (Excel.Worksheet)LibroExcel.Sheets["Hoja2"];
        HojaExcelEnt = (Excel.Worksheet)LibroExcel.Sheets["Hoja4"];
        //lastRow = HojaExcelEnt.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
    }

    public static BindingList<CROMA> ReadMyExcel()
    {
        cromaList.Clear();
        foreach (string Rango in ListaRangos)
        {
            var datoexcel = HojaExcel.Cells.Range[Rango].Value2;

            cromaList.Add(new CROMA
            {
                ID_EXCEL = datoexcel.GetValue(1, 1).ToString(),
                TAG = datoexcel.GetValue(3, 1).ToString(),
                NOMBRE = datoexcel.GetValue(4, 1).ToString(),
                Qg = datoexcel.GetValue(6, 1).ToString(),
                C1 = datoexcel.GetValue(8, 1).ToString(),
                C2 = datoexcel.GetValue(9, 1).ToString(),
                C3 = datoexcel.GetValue(10, 1).ToString(),
                iC4 = datoexcel.GetValue(11, 1).ToString(),
                nC4 = datoexcel.GetValue(12, 1).ToString(),
                iC5 = datoexcel.GetValue(13, 1).ToString(),
                nC5 = datoexcel.GetValue(14, 1).ToString(),
                C6 = datoexcel.GetValue(15, 1).ToString(),
                CO2 = datoexcel.GetValue(16, 1).ToString(),
                H2S = datoexcel.GetValue(17, 1).ToString(),
                N2 = datoexcel.GetValue(18, 1).ToString()
            });
        }
        return cromaList;
    }


    public static void WriteToExcel2(CROMA lsc)
    {
        //if (lastRow != null)
        try
            {
                lastRow += 1;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 2] = lsc.ID_EXCEL;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 4] = lsc.TAG;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 5] = lsc.NOMBRE;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 7] = lsc.Qg;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 10] = lsc.C1;
                HojaExcelEnt.Cells[lastRow, 11] = lsc.C2;

                //cromaList.Add(cromaExcel);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        LibroExcel.Save();
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        LibroExcel.Close(true);
        Myapp.Quit();
    }
  }
}
```

el metodo ReadMyExcel es llamado po run boton para cargarlo al DGV

```
  private void btnCroma_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyExcel.InicializarExcel();
        dgvCroma.DataSource = MyExcel.ReadMyExcel();
        MyExcel.Close();
    }
```

el metodo WriteToExcel2 es lanzado por el otro boton

```
 private void btnGuardar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CROMA> lsC = new List<CROMA>();


        MyExcel.InicializarExcel();

        for (int i = 0; i < dgvEntrada.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //for (int j = 0; j < dgvEntrada.Columns.Count; j++)
            //{
                //if (dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[j + 1].Value != null)
                //{
                    CROMA cromanew = new CROMA
                    {

                        ID_EXCEL = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                        TAG = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                        NOMBRE = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                        Qg = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                        C1 = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                        C2 = dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == null ? "" : dgvEntrada.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()


                    };

                   //lsC.Add(cromanew);

                    MyExcel.WriteToExcel2(cromanew);

                //}


            //}

        }

        dgvEntrada.Rows.Clear();
        dgvEntrada.Refresh();
        MyExcel.Close();
    }
```

al menos a mi me quedo de este modo, tal vez alguien pueda optimizarlo mas, saludo.